# How to add a temporary image uploaded from external url to product image data set and view in image section in magento 2 admin product edit page?

Tags: product, admin, product-images, magento2.4.5p1

I want to add custom image temporary path to existing product images data and load in the edit product page.

I have override the **product-gallery.js** and **gallery.phtml** file from `module-catalog` in my custom module.

click on a image and in the popup i am sending ajax call( product-gallery.js mixing file) to an external url and get image file and move the image to a temporary path. Like below

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'mage/template',
'uiRegistry',
'mage/url'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, registry, urlBuilder) {
'use strict';

var galleryWidgetMixin = {
    /**
     * Added confirming for modal closing
     *
     * @returns {Element}
     */
     _initDialog: function () {
        var $dialog = $(this.dialogContainerTmpl());

        $dialog.modal({
            'type': 'slide',
            title: $.mage.__('Image Detail'),
            buttons: [],

            /** @inheritdoc */
            opened: function () {
                $dialog.trigger('open');
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            closed: function () {
                $dialog.trigger('close');
            }
        });

        $dialog.on('open', this.onDialogOpen.bind(this));
        $dialog.on('close', function () {
            var $imageContainer = $dialog.data('imageContainer');

            $imageContainer.removeClass('active');
            $dialog.find('#hide-from-product-page').remove();
        });

        //-----
        $dialog.on('click', '[data-role=background-remover]', $.proxy(function (e) {
            let imageUrl = $("#current-image-url").val();
            let actionUrl = $("#controller-url").val();
            let productId = $("#product_id").val();
            let productSku = $("#product_sku").val();
            var self = this;
            jQuery.ajax({
                showLoader: true, 
                url: actionUrl,
                data: {img:imageUrl, sku:productSku, id:productId},
                type: "POST"
            }).done(function (data) {
                if(data==1){
                    $('#hide-from-product-page').trigger('click');

                    $('[data-role=dialog]').trigger("closeModal");
                    //gallery().reloadGallery('product_gallery');
                    //self._contentUpdated();
                }
            });
        }, this));
        //------

        $dialog.on('change', '[data-role="image-description"]', function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target),
                targetName = target.attr('name'),
                desc = target.val(),
                imageData = $dialog.data('imageData');

            this.element.find('input[type="hidden"][name="' + targetName + '"]').val(desc);

            imageData.label = desc;
            imageData['label_default'] = desc;

            this.element.trigger('updateImageTitle', {
                imageData: imageData
            });
        }.bind(this));

        this.$dialog = $dialog;
    }
};

return function (targetWidget) {
    $.widget('mage.productGallery', targetWidget, galleryWidgetMixin);

    return $.mage.productGallery;
};
});
```

After close the popup i want to show the temporary image with the existing images and let admin to save. How to add the additional image to `imageData`?

[image]
In the gallery.phtml file the image is processing with following lines.

```
.....some code go here.....
<?php foreach ($block->getImageTypes() as $typeData) {
    ?>
    <input name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($typeData['name']) ?>"
           data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($formName) ?>"
           class="image-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($typeData['code']) ?>"
           type="hidden"
           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($typeData['value']) ?>"/>
    <?php
} ?>

<script id="<?= $block->getHtmlId() ?>-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <div class="image item<% if (data.disabled == 1) { %> hidden-for-front<% } %>"
         data-role="image">
        <input type="hidden"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($elementName) ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][position]"
               value="<%- data.position %>"
               data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($formName) ?>"
               class="position"/>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($elementName) ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][file]"
               data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($formName) ?>"
               value="<%- data.file %>"/>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($elementName) ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][value_id]"
               data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($formName) ?>"
               value="<%- data.value_id %>"/>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($elementName) ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][label]"
               data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($formName) ?>"
               value="<%- data.label %>"/>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($elementName) ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][disabled]"
               data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($formName) ?>"
               value="<%- data.disabled %>"/>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($elementName) ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][media_type]"
               data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($formName) ?>"
               value="image"/>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($elementName) ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][removed]"
               data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($formName) ?>"
               value=""
               class="is-removed"/>

        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <img class="product-image"
                 data-role="image-element"
                 src="<%- data.url %>"
                 alt="<%- data.label %>"/>

            <div class="actions">
                <button type="button"
                        class="action-remove"
                        data-role="delete-button"
                        title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Delete image')) ?>">
                <span>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Delete image')) ?>
                </span>
                </button>
                <div class="draggable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-fade"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Hidden')) ?></span></div>
        </div>


        <div class="item-description">
            <div class="item-title" data-role="img-title"><%- data.label %></div>
            <div class="item-size">
                <span data-role="image-dimens"></span>, <span data-role="image-size"><%- data.sizeLabel %></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="item-roles" data-role="roles-labels">
            <?php
            foreach ($block->getImageTypes() as $typeData) {
                ?>
                <li data-role-code="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($typeData['code']) ?>"
                    class="item-role item-role-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($typeData['code']) ?>">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($typeData['label']) ?>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```